# Why the variable 't' exist in the output?

Tags: python, function, sympy

After running this code, the output is an expression in terms of 't', if there should not be 't' in the output. How can i solve this?

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *
n=2;z=1
x = [sp.symbols('x%d' % i) for i in range(8*n-4)]
t=sp.symbols('t ')
B=zeros(n,n)
number = range(n)
for i in number:
   for j in number:
       if i<j :
           B[i,j]=0
       else :
           B[i,j]=factorial(i+j)/(2**j*factorial(j)*factorial(i-j))
PS=Matrix(1,n,x[0:n]);PI=Matrix(1,n,x[n:2*n]);PH=Matrix(1,n,x[2*n:3*n]);PL=Matrix(1,n,x[3*n:4*n])
TS=[[1]];TI=[[1]];TH=[[1]];TL=[[1]]
for i in range(n-1):
    TS.append([t**(x[4*n+i]+i+1)])
    TI.append([t**(x[5*n+i-1]+i+1)])
    TH.append([t**(x[6*n+i-2]+i+1)])
    TL.append([t**(x[7*n+i-3]+i+1)])
MTS=Matrix(TS);MTI=Matrix(TI);MTH=Matrix(TH);MTL=Matrix(TL)
S=PS*B*MTS;I=PI*B*MTI;H=PH*B*MTH;L=PL*B*MTL
#CONVERT SYMPY MATRICES TO NUMPY ONE
S0=np.array(S);I0=np.array(I);H0=np.array(H);L0=np.array(L)
GS=zeros(n,n);GI=zeros(n,n);GH=zeros(n,n);GL=zeros(n,n)
for i in range(n):
   if i==0:
      GS[i,i]=0
      GI[i,i]=0
      GH[i,i]=0
      GL[i,i]=0
   else:
      GS[i,i]=simplify(gamma(x[4*n+i-1]+i+1)/gamma(x[4*n+i-1]+i+1-z))
      GI[i,i]=simplify(gamma(x[5*n+i-2]+i+1)/gamma(x[5*n+i-2]+i+1-z))
      GH[i,i]=simplify(gamma(x[6*n+i-3]+i+1)/gamma(x[6*n+i-3]+i+1-z))
      GL[i,i]=simplify(gamma(x[7*n+i-4]+i+1)/gamma(x[7*n+i-4]+i+1-z))
DS=simplify(t**(-z)*PS*B*GS*MTS)
DI=simplify(t**(-z)*PI*B*GI*MTI)
DH=simplify(t**(-z)*PH*B*GH*MTH)
DL=simplify(t**(-z)*PL*B*GL*MTL)
RS=DS[0,0]-(.0043217-.125*S[0,0]*I[0,0]-(.002+.0008)*S[0,0])
RI=DI[0,0]-(.125*S[0,0]*I[0,0]+.0056*H[0,0]*I[0,0]+.029*L[0,0]-(.002+.0008+.025+.35)*I[0,0])
RH=DH[0,0]-(.535-.0056*H[0,0]*I[0,0]+.35*I[0,0]-(.002+.0008)*H[0,0])
RL=DL[0,0]-(.025*I[0,0]-(.002+.0008+.029)*L[0,0])
R=simplify(RS**2+RI**2+RH**2+RL**2)
def f(t):
   return R
print(f(t))
```

For next calculation ,I need to define R as function in term of 't'

Comment: Where the code says `R=simplify(RS**2+RI**2+RH**2+RL**2)`, what do you think this means? What kind of result do you expect `R` to have? What do you think the next lines of code after that do? What **exactly** do you see? What do you think you should see instead, and **why** do you think you should see that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not find the bug for you here; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre].

Comment: I expect R be an expression in term of t and another variables, but in next step i want to integrate from R with respect to variable 't'(not with using integrate()caommand)

Comment: Okay, and what part of the code is supposed to cause the function to be integrated? Are you looking for a definite integral, or an indefinite integral? If it is definite, what should the bounds be?

Comment: The integration is my next step. in this step i need to define R as function because in next step i want to use a numerical method like gauss-legendre integration needs 
 to substitution

Comment: Okay, so did you try to read the Sympy documentation, in order to understand how to do numerical integration? - Actually, Sympy is specifically designed for *symbolic* integration. An indefinite integral will necessarily also have `t` in it (and be a Sympy formula); it has to be evaluated at the bounds of integration to get a definite integral.

Comment: Yes i read  he Sympy documentation

Comment: The symbolic integration with using integrate() command is very slow and i need to use numerical integration while my expression is symbolic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to create `f(t)` so it will give you a value no matter what value for `t` you send it, you probably mean

```py
def f(x):
   return R.subs(t, x)
```

or

```py
from sympy import lambdify
f = lambdify(t, R)
```

So `f(t)` will just give you the symbolic `R` (because your substitution didn't do anything) whereas `f(1)` will give you the value of `R` after replacing `t` with 1.

It is important to understand that the expressions are static in the sense that

```py
>>> y = var('x')  # y is assigned a symbol 'x'
>>> x = 1         # x is assigned a value of 1
>>> y             # you did not change the value of y /!\
x
>>> y.subs(x, 1)  # you replace x with 1 to give a new expression
1
>>> y             # but you still didn't change y
x
```